# How to store and get binary files from GridFS

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I am not sure if this is the way I should store the binary file into mongoDB using GridFS. The following code is the code i have written:

```
def write_GridFS_object(file_path,file_name):
     with open(file_path) as mydoc:
          fs.put(mydoc,filename=file_name)
```

This is the code that I written to get the binary file from mongoDB using GridFS:

```
def get_binary_file(file_id):
    collection = db.fs.chunks
    data =  collection.find_one({"files_id": file_id},{"_id":0,"data":1})
    data1 = str(data)
    fo = open("binary.vw", "w")
    fo.write(data1)
    fo.close()
```

The weird thing is it returns me

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

I am not very sure is this what a binary file should be printing out as mine don't have such characters.

Anyone can assist on retrieving the storing/binary file?

Comment: Have you tried the [gridfs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/#module-gridfs) package?

Comment: what u mean @chridam

Comment: That package is an implementation of GridFS on top of pymongo, exposing a file-like interface which has useful methods that you can use, in particular the [**`get(file_id)`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/#gridfs.GridFS.get) method for the above use case.

Comment: @chridam it doesn't help. Does \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0... looks like a binary file to u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may be correct. When you print a string in Python 2 and its contents include "\x00", that's the "nil" character, ASCII code 0. If your binary file is a bunch of nil characters, then it looks like you've correctly stored it in GridFS.

Try this in Python:

```
print repr(open(my_file, 'rb').read())
```

Does it look the same as this?:

```
print repr(GridFS(db).get(file_id).read())
```

If so, you've stored your data correctly.

I suggest using PyMongo's GridFS to read the data, it's easier and you'll avoid bugs that way. For example you have a bug in your code here:

```
data =  collection.find_one({"files_id": file_id},{"_id":0,"data":1})
data1 = str(data)
```

I believe you mean:

```
data1 = data['data']
```

If binary.vw differs from your input file, that bug is the likely cause.